# read stream byte from FileDescriptor

Tags: android, stream

I am beginner in android and java.

However, I want use MediaRecorder for recording voice and get data recorded as byte[], I write following code :

```
ParcelFileDescriptor[] fileDescriptors = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
ParcelFileDescriptor readFD = fileDescriptors[0];
ParcelFileDescriptor writeFD = fileDescriptors[1];
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(writeFD.getFileDescriptor());
recorder.setMaxDuration(6000);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();

    recorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            Log.d("voice", "onError");
            mediaRecorder.release();
        }
    });
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            Log.d("voice", "onInfo");
            mediaRecorder.release();
        }
    });

    InputStream inputStream = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(readFD);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    int read = -1;
    byte[] data = new byte[4000];


    while ((read = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length))  != -1) {
         byteArrayOutputStream.write(data, 0, read);
    }

    byte[] byteResult = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
 return byteResult;
```

I have a big problem with this, I debugging code, When i got to this line :

```
while ((read = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length))  != -1) {
         byteArrayOutputStream.write(data, 0, read);
    }
```

After a few laps of the while, android studio show me message and say : "the Application is running " and i had to stop it....

anybody can help me and tell me what is code wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this function [available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

```
while ((inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length))  != -1) {
     read = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length);
     byteArrayOutputStream.write(data, 0, read);
}
```